# Properties of matrices whose columns are permutations

Tags: permutations, permutation-matrices

I have a square matrix $G$ of size $n \times n$ in which each column is a random permutations of $[1,n]$, for example:

```
1 1 3 4 
2 2 1 1
3 3 2 2
4 4 4 3
```

when $n=4$.

My question is, can I always find a number between $1$ and $n$, call it $x$, such that:

For any other number between 1 and $n$, call it $j$, I can find a
column in which $x$ appears after $j$, and the columns are different for each $j$?

For example, in the matrix above, the answer is yes. The value $x=4$.

Because in column $1$, $2$ is above $4$.

In column $2$, $1$ is above $4$.

And in column $3$, $3$ is above $4$.

Can I always find the number $x$ in any given matrix composed of permutations? And how many $x$'s can I find?

Comment: These are not permutations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

Comment: Consider a matrix with one column.

Comment: I think Lereu means that your matrix is not a "permutation matrix". The Wikipedia article you link even says that permutation matrices only have $0$s and $1$s as entries. So the tag permutation-matrices doesn't apply, and you should change your title to something like "matrices whose columns are permutations". Also, does the matrix have to be square? Must its columns be distinct? Is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1  & 2 & 3 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ a counterexample, for instance?

Comment: No, it is not a counterexample. In the above matrix a is above 4 in the first column, 2 above 4 in the second column, and 3 above 4 in the 3rd column.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please [edit] to tell us what you are assuming about the number of columns. If you are asking what I think you are, then I think the answer is yes and you might be able to prove it by looking at the multiset of entries in the last row.

Comment: Thank you Ethan. I've tried this approach and the answer is clear when there is a unique element in the multiset. I'm unsure on how to generalize it - but see what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is asking. Every column has [n] in some order. Are you asking if you can always find a value x such that for every column there is some other value y above it in a different position?

Answer (score 1):

Let us prove it by induction on $n$. This is trivial for $n = 1$. Now, assume it is true at rank $n$. Let $G = (\sigma_j(i))_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant n + 1}$ where each $\sigma_i$ is a permutation of $[\![1,n + 1]\!]$.

Let $a = \sigma_{n + 1}(1)$ be the integer that appears at the top right of $G$. Consider $H$ the matrix formed of the elements of $G$ where all the $a$ and the last column has been removed. Formally, $H = (\tilde{\sigma}_j(i))_{1 \leqslant i,j \leqslant n}$, where
\begin{align*}
\tilde{\sigma}_j(i) & = \sigma_j(i) \textrm{ if } i < \sigma_j^{-1}(a),\\
\tilde{\sigma}_j(i) & = \sigma_j(i - 1) \textrm{ if } i \geqslant \sigma_j^{-1}(a)
\end{align*}
Each $\tilde{\sigma}_j$ is a permutation of $[\![1,n + 1]\!]\backslash\{a\}$ so up to relabelling the coefficients of $H$, it verifies the wanted hypothesis and it has size $n \times n$. By induction, there exists an $x \in [\![1,n + 1]\!]\backslash\{a\}$ and an injective function $\rho : [\![1,n + 1]\!]\backslash\{a,x\} \rightarrow [\![1,n]\!]$ such that for all $i \in [\![1,n + 1]\!]\backslash\{a,x\}$, $i$ appears before $x$ in the column $\rho(i)$. In other words, $\tilde{\sigma}_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(i) < \tilde{\sigma}_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(x)$.

Notice that it implies that $\sigma_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(i) < \sigma_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(x)$. In other words, this property remains true in $G$. Extend $\rho$ with $\rho(a) = n + 1$ and notice that $\sigma_{\rho(a)}^{-1}(a) = \sigma_{n + 1}^{-1}(a) = 1 < \sigma_{n + 1}^{-1}(x) = \sigma_{\rho(a)}^{-1}(x)$ ($a$ apprears before $x$ in the last column).

It proves that $x$ fits because for all $i \in [\![1,n + 1]\!]\backslash\{x\}$, $\sigma_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(i) < \sigma_{\rho(i)}^{-1}(x)$, meaning that $i$ appears before $x$ in the column $\rho(i)$, and $\rho$ is injective. Actually, I think we can pretty easily adapt the proof to show that $n - 1$ columns are enough.